# pdf file not opening on android phone

Tags: asp.net, webforms, pdf-generation

I am trying to show a pdf file embedded on my web page as soon as the web page loads. This is what I am doing to show the pdf file on my aspx page:

```
<asp:Literal  ID="ltEmbed" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

and in my .cs page

```
string embed = "<object class=\"ss-pdfjs-viewer\" data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\"    allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen>";
            embed += "</object>";
            string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Session["RequestType"] + "_" + HttpContext.Current.Session["MailID"].ToString() + ".pdf";
            ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/Documents/" + fileName));
```

everything works fine. I can open this pdf file in my web application, iphone, but not in android phone.

I am not sure why it is not working in android and all other places.